# what is the number of cores in building gem5

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, gem5

I want to use the below command to build gem5 which installed in VirtualBox.
I put two CPU in the setting of VirtualBox. what will be the number of n that should I used in this command?

```
scons build/ARM/gem5.opt -jn
```

Answer (score 0):

`-jn` means `n` CPUs will be used, you can check it with `htop`.

What you usually want is `` -j `nproc` ``  to use all available cores.